# open new Outlook from website, too long mailTo Link, *.eml file bcc field not loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, outlook-2010, eml

I'm trying to open a `*.eml` file with Microsoft Outlook 2010 and got problems with the `bcc` field.

Here is my `eml` file:

```
To: example@domain.com
Subject: Mail Subject
cc: cc@domain.com
bcc: bcc@domain.com
Content-Type: text/plain
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Unsent: 1

Mail content
```

When I open this eml file with Outlook all entries work fine, except `bcc`.
How can i bring the `bcc` field to work?

**Edit**

I basicly want the same behavior of a `mailto` link on a webpage. The user should click on a link and the default mailprogram (which is Outlook in the office where the software is used) should open. `mailto` links work fine until the link is not longer than about 2000 characters. In my case, the informations that I need to pass to Outlook are much longer than 2000 characters, so I tried to generate an `*.eml` file which doesn't work as expected.

So what I need:

- a link similar to a `mailto` link
- must work with more than 2000 characters
- must work in Google Chrome & Outlook 2010

What I got:

- PHP
- JavaScript with jQuery

Comment: Browsers have limits on url lengths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my given problem.

MailTo links are still too long and *.eml files won't work. But it's possible to generate a *.vbs file (Visual Basic Script) which will open up a new Outlook E-Mail send form with all the fields I need and a very long Body (tested with over 50000 characters). Here is a sample code for such an *.vbs file:

```
'Create an Outlook application object 
Set objoutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 

'Create Message 
Set objmessage = objoutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
objmessage.TO = "mail1@domain.com;mail2@example.de"
objmessage.CC = "cc1@x.com;cc2@y.de"
objmessage.BCC = "bcc@domain.com"
objmessage.Subject = "E-Mail Subject"
objmessage.Body = "Here comes some text, followed by a newLine" & vbNewLine _
& "and here is a second Line with some special characters like the paragraph: " & chr(167) & ", a german umlaut: " & chr(228) & " or some quotes: "". Hope this will help!"
objmessage.display

set objmessage = Nothing
set objoutlookApp = Nothing

wscript.quit
```

Comment: This is very useful, until you realize you need UTF-8 support

Answer (score 4):

For your **edit**, you can use forms in this way:

```
<form name="mailform" action="mailto:youremail@domain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="bcc" value="youremailBCC@domain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Email subject">
    <input type="hidden" name="Body" value="A Big body ">
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.mailform.submit()">send email</a>
```

I used this on an Ubuntu machine, with Thunderbird and Gmail web as default mail client and Google Chrome and Firefox as browsers and both worked. I don't know about outlook, you need to test it for outlook yourself ;) But notice, generally mailto links depends on user's machine.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, but it doesn't work for me. I get the same issue as I get when I use a long mailto link. In fact this form generates such a link using JavaScript and passes it to Outlook. I think Outlook is the problem here, not the Browser or the HTML / JS code

Comment: mailto url schema is limited to ~2000 chars because of the GET restriction

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably outside of your eml file. I've tested your file on my OSX machine and the bcc is showing in the Mail app.

However: [bcc is by default not shown in outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299804) so now you could have 2 situations:

1. bcc is not shown, but might be set from your eml file, if this is not an issue: success!
2. since bcc is not shown outlook might not set it. In that case you'd have to make it so that everyone enables bcc to be shown by default. (walk by all desktops, ask the adminstrator, ...) This might be a blocker if you are not allowed to require this change.

Comment: I already tried to set up the Outlook client on my desktop so that the bcc field is shown. But it's still empty after opening the eml file.

Comment: Hmmm in that case it might be that there is just no solution. I've read about some implementations that do not save bcc headers, since they are meant to be hidden and would otherwise still be shown to all recipients. This might be a side-effect of something like that.